# VS 2008 C++ VS_VERSION_INFO

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have the following code in my DLL rc file:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 4,2,3,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 4,2,3,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Added Presenters disconnection"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "my comp"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "DLL for Connect"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "4, 2, 3, 0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "mydll"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2013"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "mydll.DLL"
            VALUE "ProductName", "mydllDynamic Link Library"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "4, 2, 3, 0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END
```

I am working on VS2008, Win7.

When I go to the file properties from windows explorer, to the details tab, I do not see the comments line!

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Windows (starting with either Vista or 7, I forget which) no longer display the Comments field in the File Properties dialog.  It's very annoying.  :-(

Comment: So what can be the alternative? The file description?

Comment: @dushkin: Yes, I think `FileDescription` is your best bet.